# How to turn .scn from Documents folder into SCNNode programmatically?

Tags: ios, scenekit, arkit

I have a `.scn` file in a folder in the `Documents` folder in the iPhone. I've been trying to use `SCNSceneSource` to turn the `.scn` file as a `SCNNode`

```
//fileDestFolderURL is the folder that holds the .scn file
let sceneSource = SCNSceneSource(url: fileDestFolderURL, options: [:])
let scene = sceneSource?.scene(options: [:])
print(scene) //prints nil
print(scene?.rootNode) //prints nil
```

However, I keep getting `nil` :(

My ultimate goal is to take the `SCNNode` and add it to an `ARSCNView`.

If anyone could provide their input it would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use [`SCNScene.init(url:options:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/scenekit/scnscene/1522660-init) instead of `SCNSceneSource` (which is mostly meant for Collada files).

Comment: Do I need to pass any specific options to make this work? It returns nil for me even though the URL to the file is correct.

Answer (score -1):

I'm using Objective-C to accomplish what you're asking. Here is some translated code that might help you. Here is an example with a Chair .scn model. I've noticed htat it is better to have the .scn file in the Models.scnassets folder

```
class Chair {
    func loadModel() {
        let virtualObjectScene = SCNScene(named:"Models.scnassets/chair/chair.scn"")
        let wrapperNode = SCNNode()
        for child: SCNNode in virtualObjectScene?.rootNode?.childNodes {
            wrapperNode.addChildNode(child)
        }
        addChildNode(wrapperNode)
    }
}
```

What I do is instantiate an object of this Chair class and then call loadModel on this object. After that I can just add it as a child node to the scene's root node and it appears in the scene.

Comment: But the problem is my `.scn` file is not in my app when I pre-run (i.e. its not in my `Models.scnassets` of my app). I'm downloading the `.scn` file, so its in the `Documents` folder of the iPhone. So I can't call `SCNScene(named:"Models.scnassets/chair/chair.scn")`

Comment: Have you tried this function with changing the filepath name to wherever your .scn file is in the Documents Directory? I've used it with .scn files outside of Models.scnassets and it does work as well.